# How to create Dynamic multi dropdown in laravel 5.6?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have just started with Laravel. I don't understand the tutorials I search on google.

Here is the first dropdown:

```
 {!! Form::select('attribute_type_id',$attributes, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Here is how I get `$attributes` in Controller.

```
$attributes = AttributeType::pluck('attribute_type', 'id');
    return view('product_attributes.create', compact('id','products', 'attributes'));
```

Here is the 2nd dropdown.

```
{!! Form::select('attribute_sub_type_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

1. Here are the columns of the `AttributeType(id, attribute_type)`.
2. Here are the columns of the `AttributeSubType(id, attribute_type_id, attribute_sub_type)`.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 or 5.6? Only add relevant tags

Comment: Are you want to load data to 2nd dropdown when user selected the 1st dropdown?

Comment: I have 2 tables. 1st drop down select id from table A and 2nd drop down match id from table B.